# Python нарисовать график S-образной функции зависимости

Tags: python, matplotlib

Помогите правильно нарисовать график S-образной функции зависимости.

Мой код:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def solwave(x, a, b):
    y = []
    for xx in x:        
        if xx<=a:     
            y += [0.0]
        elif a<xx<=(0.5*(a+b)):
            y += [2*np.float64(((xx-a)*(xx-a))/((b-a)*(b-a)))]
        elif (0.5*(a+b))<xx<b:
            y += [(1-2)*np.float64(((b-xx)*(b-xx))/((b-a)*(b-a)))]
        elif xx>=b:         
            y += [1.0]  
    return np.array(y)    

plt.title('Графік функції приналежності') 
plt.grid() 
x = np.linspace(0,10,256)
y = 0.5+0*x
# параметри
a=2.5
b=7.0
# вісь
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 1.2])
# малюємо графік
plt.plot(x, solwave(x, a, b), lw=2, color="mediumseagreen")
plt.axvline(b, ymax=0.83, color='blue', linestyle="--")
plt.plot(x, y, color='black')
# відображаємо графік
plt.show()
```

Результат такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно получится так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Формула неправильная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

График S-образной зависимости

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-1,1,256)
y=1/(1+np.exp(-10*x))
plt.plot(y)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, и что это за загадочная формула?

```
y = 0.5+0*x
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Формулу y = 0.5 + 0*x я использовал для построения черной линии на графике.

Comment: @Yura Zelinski  горизонтальная линия на графике проводится функцией hlines(), первым параметром которой передается скаляр(не список!!!) - уровень на котором рисуется линия.